# Rigid structure which is generically homogeneous

Tags: lo.logic, forcing

Is it possible to have a structure $T$ in some language which is rigid in $V$, but in a cardinal-preserving extension $T$ is homogeneous (in a suitable sense of the word)?

If this is not possible, is it at least consistent? If not, then what if we remove the requirement that cardinals are preserved?

Comment: A structure $M$ is homogeneous if, whenever $A \mapsto B$ is a partial elementary map from $M$ to itself, where $|A|, |B| < |M|$, then for all $a \in M$ there is $b \in M$ such that $Aa \mapsto Bb$ is partial elementary.

So this in fact compatible with rigidity: say let $M$ be any structure of size $\kappa$ for the language with $\kappa$-many constant symbols. Then $M$ is homogeneous and rigid.

You probably want to ask for many automorphisms, rather than homogeneity.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is at least consistent. See:

Fuchs, Gunter, [Club degrees of rigidity and almost Kurepa trees](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00153-012-0306-7). Arch. Math. Logic 52 (2013), no. 1-2, 47–66.

In this paper a (very) rigid Souslin tree $T$ is constructed such that after forcing with $T$ itself, $\aleph_2$-many automorphisms of $T \restriction Lim$
are added. So it suffices to consider the structure $T \restriction Lim$
and force with $T$.